# Entity Framework Error on Many to Many Relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have the following class for appointments:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int appointmentId { get; set; }

    public int Mins { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    //Navagation Properties
    public CompanyInformation Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Customer { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Staff { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public Appointment ParentAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

and the following Service Class:

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int serviceId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public bool isPublished { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyInformation Company { get; set; }

    public UserProfile defaultStaff { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between these two by:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().HasMany(e => e.Appointments).WithMany(e => e.Services);
```

in the OnModelCreating of the DbContext. when I try to update the db I get the following error.

```
 Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ServiceAppointments_dbo.Appointments_Appointment_appointmentId' on table 'ServiceAppointments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I've researched it a bit and found that the problem is with the Cascade delete and that I should disable it. The problem is that I don't know how and the options that I've found doesn't seem to work for me (they are apparently for one-to-many relationships). any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That should work fine as it is** (*you don't need the mapping for many-to-many, that works by convention*).
Which version EF/CF do you have ? But anyway, since it doesn't...

a) **Try removing the convention** as @Lajos mentioned - that should do the trick,

b) If that doesn't work, you can **'rewrite' the relationships manually** - and turn off cascade, something like this...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.ParentAppointment)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceAppointment>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.ServiceId, x.AppointmentId });

modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceAppointment>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Service)
    .WithMany(x => x.Appointments)
    .HasForeignKey(at => at.ServiceId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceAppointment>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Appointment)
    .WithMany(x => x.Services)
    .HasForeignKey(at => at.AppointmentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Just change collections in both classes to...

```
// public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ServiceAppointment> Appointments { get; set; }

// public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ServiceAppointment> Services { get; set; }

public class ServiceAppointment
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}
```

...that should definitely resolve the issue. Though you lose the 'Services' 'Appointments' direct navigation (all goes via ServiceAppointments)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
      {

         modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

     modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

     modelBuilder.Entity<Service>()
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

      }
```

Comment: Lajos, that other part has no way of working - good point about the convention.